# Android Image Button tint only one color

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

I am writing an app where I have an icon on an image button that looks like a paintbrush with paint on it. When ever the user changes colors, I want the paint on the brush to change to the chosen color.

I have tried making the icon's paint white and tinting the image button, but this just tints the whole paintbrush image. I have also tried setColorFilter() without success.  Anyone know how I might be able to accomplish this without creating a drawable resource for every color?

Edit:
Perhaps I should clarify,

If I have an icon that looks like this [image: paintbrush plain]

Then when the user selects red, it should look like this [image: red brush]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yeah.  Is possible with a white image.  The image should be designed in such a way that the color area in the brush icon alone should be in white color.  Then you can apply colorFilter on the image to change the white color alone to any other color(probably the user selected color)

```
imageBtn.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0xffff0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

And this one below that apply to background

```
imageBtn.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xffff0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

I tried it with chessboard image which has white and black squares, I could change the white squares to any color with the colorFilter.

It will definitely help.

Comment: This colors the whole icon. I edited my post for clarification

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton11); // image button
            imgBtn.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray), Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: This colors the whole icon. I edited my post for clarification